# Liferay concatenate and compress javascript

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to figure out how to achieve compression and minification for all my js files. Currently i have them in a hook plugin under `/html/js/mycustomjs/` folder.

I understand that liferay has its own mechanism to compress javascripts, in barebone.jsp or everything.jsp, and found the list of files declared in the `javascript.barebone.files` and `javascript.everything.files` properties on `portal.properties`.

The question is, can i use this mechanism to compress js files of my own ? should i override such properties in the `portal-ext.properties` ? Or should i just use the `MinifierFilter` by myself ?

Moreover, is a hook plugin the right place to put js files that i want available on all of the portal's sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the `javascript.bundle.dependencies=` and `javascript.bundle.ids=` properties in `portal-ext.properties`, see http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/javascri-3

Something like this:

```
javascript.my.files =\  
   jquery-1.8.3.js,\
   my-script.js

javascript.bundle.ids=\
   javascript.barebone.files,\
   javascript.everything.files,\
   javascript.my.files  


javascript.bundle.dependencies[javascript.barebone.files]=javascript.my.files
```

Furthermore, I don't think that the hook plugin is a right place for such requirements. My opinion the better way is to put the javascripts central to the theme.

Comment: i ended up choosing this solution and creating a jsp of my own, to include all the javascripts, by adding this jsp to the url regex of the minifier filter in liferay-web.xml. As to the javascript placement in the theme, that would not work for multiple websites, so i ended up by keeping them in the hook. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @Mark how can you include javascript files contained in a theme? I can see how this works with a hook because it will include it with the javascript in ROOT/html/js but what do the paths to the javascript files need to look like in `javascript.my.files` if the files are in the theme?