# Liferay 6.1.20 : Minimize and bundle theme Javascript

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

Is there a way to apply Liferay's built-in javascript minimizing and bundling capability to the javascript I've included in my theme?  I have `javascript.fast.load=true` in portal-ext.properties and Liferay's javascript is getting bundled & minified in everything.jsp as expected. Also, all portlet javascript that is included via a portlet's liferay-portal.xml file is getting minified as expected.  However, I've got many javascript files that are included in my theme because they are utilized on every page and I would like them to get minimized and bundled into `everything.jsp` along with all the Liferay portal javascript. I've tried the approach suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540178/liferay-concatenate-and-compress-javascript), but I think this will only work with a hook because the MinifyFilter will look for files to minify & bundle within the context of the portal web app, i.e. `<TOMCAT>/webapps/ROOT`. Is there a way I can specify a path to files in a different web app (the theme in this case) as the `javascript.bundle.dir` parameter? In other words, something like `javascript.bundle.dir[javascript.jquery.files]=/<theme-path>/js`.  I've tried many variations and combinations of `javascript.bundle.ids`, `javascript.bundle.dependencies`, etc. to no avail.  I know I can get around the problem by putting the javascript in a hook or putting it in portlet and embedding it in the theme but I'd really like to just keep the javascript in the theme.  Is there a reasonable way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a good way to include javascript files from the theme with the minified and bundled Liferay javascript. While you can define a javascript bundle in portal-ext.properties that includes your files, you can't order the dependencies the way you need to in order to get everything to work using only configuration. You can configure the "everything" bundle to depend on your custom bundle but that's not very useful. It would be far more useful if you could configure Liferay to use your custom bundle as the new "everything" bundle and tell Liferay that your bundle depends on Liferay's "everything" bundle. However, the actual bundle ids that are included are hard-coded in Liferay's `top_js.jspf` file. So the only way to get everything to work would be to override Liferay's definition of `javascript.everything.files` to include both Liferay's files and your custom javascript. This doesn't seem like a very good solution since it tampers with Liferay's list of included javascript which would certainly be a pain when you need to upgrade Liferay.  As Olaf suggested, you can minify and bundle the js yourself and just include it in the `portal_normal` template. That is a very reasonable solution and what I would normally recommend. Unfortunately I was in a situation where my customer was requesting that all the files be bundled in one file and we are not allowed to modify the build process.

### Hook Workaround

There is a workaround using a hook that **I don't necessarily recommend** but it does accomplish the goal of getting all javascript minimized and bundled along with Liferay's javascript. The basic process is to move the javascript from the theme into a hook, configure a new bundle in portal-ext.properties that includes all of your files, then create a jsp hook for top_js.jspf that includes your new bundle instead of the hard-coded `javascript.everything.files` or `javascript.barebones.files` bundles.  The steps are:

- Move your javascript files into a hook project and place them under html/js. This will cause
  the files to be copied to the javascript directory under the portal
  web app, i.e. `<TOMCAT_HOME>/ROOT/html/js`. This is where the Liferay
  MinifyFilter looks for javascript files to minify & bundle.
- Define a javascript bundle in `portal-ext.properties` that references
  all of your javascript files that need to be included in the bundle
  created by the MinifyFilter. Your `portal-ext.properties` file should
  look something like this:

  ```
  minifier.enabled=true
  javascript.fast.load=true

  javascript.my.js.files =\  
  jquery.1.11.1,\
  my-js-lib.js,\
  my-other-js-lib.js

  javascript.bundle.ids=\
      javascript.barebone.files,\
      javascript.everything.files,\
      javascript.my.js.files  

  javascript.bundle.dir[javascript.my.js.files]=/html/js

  # our bundle depends on all the files in the "everything" bundle
  javascript.bundle.dependencies[javascript.my.js.files]=javascript.everything.files
  ```
- Create a JSP hook for `top_js.jspf`. This file is under
  `<TOMCAT_HOME>/ROOT/html/common/themes`. It is the file that includes
  either the barebones.jsp or everything.jsp based on whether the user
  is authenticated (if the user is authenticated they get
  everything.jsp otherwise barebones.jsp is included). Replace the
  references to the `javascript.everything.files` and/or
  `javascript.barebones.files` bundles with a reference to your new
  bundle based on your requirements. For example, if you only want to
  include your javascript when the user is authenticated you just have
  to replace references to `javascript.everything.files`. 
  Specifically, you make the following changes:

#### This line:

```
<script src="<%= HtmlUtil.escape(PortalUtil.getStaticResourceURL(request, themeDisplay.getCDNDynamicResourcesHost() + themeDisplay.getPathJavaScript() + "/everything.jsp", "minifierBundleId=javascript.everything.files", javaScriptLastModified)) %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

#### is changed to this:

```
<script src="<%= HtmlUtil.escape(PortalUtil.getStaticResourceURL(request, themeDisplay.getCDNDynamicResourcesHost() + themeDisplay.getPathJavaScript() + "/everything.jsp", "minifierBundleId=javascript.my.js.files", javaScriptLastModified)) %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

#### and this line:

```
javaScriptFiles = JavaScriptBundleUtil.getFileNames(PropsKeys.JAVASCRIPT_EVERYTHING_FILES);
```

#### is changed to this:

```
javaScriptFiles = JavaScriptBundleUtil.getFileNames("javascript.my.js.files");
```

### * Non-Global Hook Caveat *

If you are putting the javascript and top_js.jspf hooks in a project with other hooks and the project is configured to use non-global jsp hooks, i.e. `<custom-jsp-global>false</custom-jsp-global>` the solution becomes more complicated. This is because setting `<custom-jsp-global>true</custom-jsp-global>` makes Liferay rename your hook jsp files rather than renaming the portal's jsp files. For example, if custom-jsp-global is set to true, which is the default setting, then when I make a hook for a page called top_js.jspf, the portal will rename the original top_js.jspf file to top_js.portal.jsp and my hook file will be used instead of the original. However, when custom-jsp-global is set to false then the original file stays intact and the jsp hook file is renamed to something that includes the name of the hook like `top_js.my-hook.jspf`. This is a problem when you're creating a hook for included files such as `top_js.jspf` because the file that includes `top_js.jspf` will still reference the old file, not the hook which is named `top_js.my-hook.jspf`. This means you have to also create a hook for the file that includes your hook.  Likewise, if that file is included by another file you have to make hook for that file and so on until you reach the top level page. So, in the example of trying to create a hook for `top_js.jspf` we have to also do the following:

- Create a hook for `top_head.jspf` and replace the reference to `top_js.jspf` with a reference to our hook, `top_js.my-hook.jspf`.

#### So this line

```
<%@ include file="/html/common/themes/top_js.jspf" %>
```

#### becomes this

```
<%@ include file="/html/common/themes/top_js.my-hook.jspf" %>
```

- The `top_head.jspf` file is actually included by the theme in
  `portal_normal.vm` using a Velocity variable that is initialized in
  `init.vm` on the following line:

You need to assign `$top_head_include` to the `top_head.my-hook.jspf` hook in the theme's `init_custom.vm`, like this:

```
#set ($top_head_include = "$dir_include/common/themes/top_head.my-hook.jsp")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Theme has access to all of the HTML the portal generates. While you might need one extra file to be loaded (css gets minified for the whole theme anyway), you can easily add all of the (already) minified js files to your theme and include them in your `templates/portal-normal.ftl` implementation.

It would be as easy as having this section in portal-normal.ftl:

```
<head>
  <title>${the_title} - ${company_name}</title>
  <meta content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" name="viewport" />
  ${theme.include(top_head_include)}
  <script src="${javascript_folder}/my-minified-javascript.js"/>
</head>
```

Note: All but the `<script>` line is already in the default ftl file. This way you'll end up with two js files being loaded (the barebones or everything, plus your own), but that's not too bad. You can also add the minification to your theme's build process, so that you don't have to maintain the minified code manually.

Another alternative, which I haven't tried, is examining the use of Liferay's javascript minifier (e.g. in `webapps/ROOT/html/common/themes/tom_js.jsp`) to see how to utilize it to dynamically minify your files.

---

For completeness reason (maybe it helps someone else) I'm leaving my first answer here, which you couldn't use as you say in the first comment:

There's a section in `portal.properties`, to be overloaded in portal-ext.properties with this heading:

```
##
## JavaScript
##

#
# Set a list of JavaScript files that will be loaded automatically in
# /html/common/themes/top_js.jsp.
#
# There are two lists of files specified in the properties
# "javascript.barebone.files" and "javascript.everything.files".
#
# As the name suggests, the barebone list is the minimum list of JavaScript
# files required for most cases. The everything list includes everything
# else not listed in the barebone list.
#
# The two lists of files exist for performance reasons because
# unauthenticated users usually do not utilize all the JavaScript that is
# available. See the property "javascript.barebone.enabled" for more
# information on the logic of when the barebone list is used and when the
# everything list is used and how to customize that logic.
#
# The list of files are also merged and packed for further performance
# improvements. See the property "javascript.fast.load" for more details.
#
```

e.g. configure `javascript.everything.files` (the default is below that comment, for brevity I'm not copying that here)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I believe that will only work with files that are in a hook because the MinifyFilter looks in `<TOMCAT>/webapps/ROOT/html/js`. I've verified that fact by debugging the MinifyFilter, it gets the path to the js files using `ServletContextUtil.getRealPath(_servletContext, requestPath)`. So all files must reside in the portal's web app. The only way I know of to get them deployed there is to put them in a hook. I'm looking for a way to add javascript files from my theme to the list of `javascript.everything.files`.  Do you know of a way to do that?